# query that returns the distance between vertices u and v in graph G

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I study algorithms independently, during my studies I came across a question that I am not sure if I managed to solve it correctly.

the problem:
Given undirected connected graph G with N vertices numbered 1 . . . N and set of vertices {1 . . . N} ⊆ H. The vertices that are members of the set H are called “important vertices”.
You need performs some preprocessing on the graph G and the group H and save the result of the preprocessing, but you don’t have a lot of storage space. It may not have enough space to store a complete description of the graph G. For some given pair of vertices u, v. The vertex u is an important vertex (that is, u ∈ H ), and the vertex v is some vertex (maybe important or maybe not). You need to answer what is the distance in the graph G between the vertices u and v.

The input and output of the pre-processing algorithm (step A): For the preprocessing algorithm given:

1. Number N, which represents the number of vertices in the graph G. The given graph is connected.
2. A list of pairs of numbers between 1 and N that represent the edges in the graph G (undirected edges).
3. Number M, representing the number of important vertices.
4. List H of the M important vertices.
   The preprocessing algorithm emits a data structure that will be denoted S.

The input and output of the query answering algorithm (step B): For the query answering algorithm (step B) given:

1. The data structure S emitted by the preprocessing algorithm.
2. A pair of vertices u ∈ H and v ∈ {1 . . . N}

The query answering algorithm returns the distance between the vertices u and v in the graph G. The distance between vertices is defined to be the length of the shortest path between them in the graph. Steps A and B that both run in polynomial time in N and H. It is guaranteed that 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000 and also 1 ≤ H ≤ 40, then the data structure S has a size of 100,000 bits at most.

I'm not sure of my answer, I think I'm missing something.

This is the solution I came up with:

We start by initializing a priority queue with all the important vertices and their distances set to 0. We also initialize an array of distances for all vertices in the graph, with all distances set to infinity except for the important vertices which have distance 0. We then perform the following steps:
While the priority queue is not empty, extract the vertex with the minimum distance.
For each neighbor of the extracted vertex, compute the distance to the neighbor as the sum of the distance to the extracted vertex and the weight of the edge connecting them. If this distance is less than the current distance to the neighbor, update the distance to the neighbor and add it to the priority queue.
Repeat steps 1 and 2 until all important vertices have been extracted from the priority queue.
Explanation:
After this preprocessing step, we can answer queries about the distance between a given important vertex u and any other vertex v in the graph by simply looking up the distance to v in the array of distances computed during the preprocessing step. This lookup takes constant time, so the query answering algorithm also runs in polynomial time in N and H.

To estimate the size of the data structure S, we need to consider the storage required for the array of distances and the priority queue used in the preprocessing step. The array of distances requires N * log2(N) bits to store, since we need to store the distance to each vertex as a binary integer. The priority queue can be implemented using a binary heap, which requires at most 2 * H * log2(N) bits to store, since we need to store the index and distance of each important vertex in the heap. Therefore, the total storage required for S is at most N * log2(N) + 2 * H * log2(N) bits, which is at most 100,000 bits when N = 1000 and H = 40, as specified in the problem statement.

Comment: What does the distance between u and v have to do with the "important" vertices.  The distance will be the same whether or not u is a member of H.

Comment: The standard method of calculating the distance between two vertices is the Dijkstra algorithm.  Have you tried this?  Why does it not work in your case?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I thought of using Dijkstra, but then I need to save Dijkstra's results, I haven't found a way to save Dijkstra's results, in less than 100,000 bits. I was thinking of saving a matrix of N on H, but that's more than 10 million bits.

Comment: Suspect they're looking for d(u, u') for all pairs {u, u'} ⊆ H and d(v, H) for all v.